# How to keep track of exeptions untill the end without stopping the program in Python and then printing them together

Tags: python, exception

I am working on a project at university and my teacher told me: I would like you to change your code in manner that it always reach the end and print an output, even if exceptions occur.

I actually have written a python application that consicts in 8/9 classes that are used by `main.py` in order to elaborate datas and provide an output. Each of the classes provide one or more functionalities (ie: `xml_manager.download_from(url)`, `xml_manager.parse(xml_file)`, `xml_manager.find_value_by_tag(tag)`, ...) and they all must be showed at the end. They are strictly correlated and if one of them is missing or incorectthenthe rest of the application has no consistency. That is why I decided to implement several `try - catch` that in case of errors print a message and terminates the execution.

Here is an example:

```
# main.py
# start program

obj_a = class_a()
result_a = foo_a(some_input)    # may throw exceptions

obj_b = class_b()
result_b = foo_b(result_a)      # may throw exceptions

obj_c = class_c()
result_c = foo_b(result_b)      # may throw exceptions

print(f"Results: {result_a}, {result_b}, {result_c}")
```

How do I do keep track of what happened in each single object? My idea was to return 2 values, for example, the code above becomes:

```
# main.py
# start program

obj_a = class_a()
result_a, status_msg = foo_a(some_input)    # may throw exceptions, if status_msg is empty: there are no exceptions, else it contains a message like "Server returned 404 error"
if status_msg != "":
    # an exception occurred
    result_a = status_msg

obj_b = class_b()
result_b, status_msg = foo_b(result_a)      # may throw exceptions
if status_msg != "":
    # an exception occurred
    result_b = status_msg

obj_c = class_c()
result_c, status_msg = foo_b(result_b)      # may throw exceptions
if status_msg != "":
    # an exception occurred
    result_c = status_msg

print(f"Results: {result_a}, {result_b}, {result_c}")
```

This results must be printed on screen and at the very end of the application. Is there any better way of doing this? Is it a good idea to create a class calld output and pass it to every function as input parameter? (I used to do something similar in Java but I am not sure it is a good practice in Python)
Thanks

Comment: Put all your code in a function, then wrap the function in a `try/except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the pythonic way would be to use exceptions and handle them in the main program flow:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

class class_a:
    def foo_a(self, input):
        try:
            # logic here
            result = "Result A"
        except Exception as e:
            raise MyException("...")
        return result

messages = []
obj_a = class_a()
try:
    result_a = obj_a.foo_a(some_input)
except MyException as e:
    messages.append(str(e))
    result_a = None
```

This approach is better imo, as it follows EAFP principle and the propagation of errors at the level that makes more sense.

Comment: good idea, I am gonna try it right now!

Comment: If I have the `main` calling `foo1` that is calling `foo2` that is calling `foo3` and the exception occurs in `foo3`: do I have to intercept the exception at each "hop" or just in `foo3` and `main`?